# Overlay a view over whole screen, when using UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, hud

I want to overlay a HUD-style transparent graphic over the entire screen in a UITabBarController setup. The button to do this is in the first tab's screen (FirstViewController), and the overlay should also cover the tabs... is this possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could attach your new view to your window directly.

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myNewView];
```

Comment: The problem I have with this solution is that the overlay comes up upside-down, and does not rotate. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: The orientation is only passed to the first view controller added to your window. If you only adding a view (without the controller) you have to set the rotation of your status bar first (see the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436530/launching-app-in-landscape-orientation-causes-rotation-on-launch)

Answer (score 13):

The above solution by **Henrik P. Hessel** is Good but there is one problem with that solution. The problem is already mentioned by **elsurudo** in the comment below the Answer.

> The problem I have with this solution is that the overlay comes up
>   upside-down, and does not rotate.

I faced the same problem and I tried different things and I got one solution to eliminate that problem.

The solution is simple. You can add that `myNewView` to `UITabBarController`'s view.

```
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:myNewView];
```

Hope, it will be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

```
UIView *modal = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.window.frame];
[self.view.window addSubview:modal];
```

This might be the same as the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]` mentioned above. But I like referencing it through the current view.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [rdelmar's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23125428), I recommend putting your UITabBarController in Container View other `ViewController`. Then add your hud onto `ViewController` view.

[image: screenshot for answer]

Comment: When you reference someone else's answer, you need to mention them *by name*. I've edited your answer to comply with this. For more information, see our [referencing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 1):

I really liked what Chase Robert had written here, so I thought to provide the Swift 3. version as well:

```
    if let window = view.window {
        let subView = UIView(frame: window.frame)
        window.addSubview(subView)
    }
```

I added the condition as well, so you don't get a crash if there's no windows.