# iPad launch image and orientation...again

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, orientation

I know there's been a million questions about the iPad's orientation at launch cause I've read them all, but here's the thing I don't understand.

Nearly everything says to assume that the iPad is in portrait orientation...

BUT...you can provide a landscape launch image and if it will use it.

So, somewhere, it knows that the device is in landscape...BUT there doesn't seem to be anyplace that I can find out if the landscape image was used at launch time!

I've tried:

```
orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

And they always say portrait...even when it's not.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These are some links that has the answer of your question.
 1. [Landscape Lauch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436530/launching-app-in-landscape-orientation-causes-rotation-on-launch) 
 2. [Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647786/landscape-mode-only-for-iphone-or-ipad)
 3. [Apple Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1588/_index.html)

Every Link has proper information your want to know.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already read these and they don't answer my question. (1) My app already launches in landscape mode and it does use the landscape launch image. (2) I don't want to force it to launch in landscape mode...I just want to know when it does. (3) My launch images and plist are all correct. As I said...the iPad OS knows when it's launching an app in landscape mode because it's using the correct launch image...but I need to know that somehow and every clue to orientation just says Portrait at launch...whether it is or not. There HAS TO BE some way to know correctly.